# Gathering info on Cluster Shared Volumes

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I'd like to let our monitoring software (Nagios) start a powershell script that checks our clustersharedvolumes and returns status for all volumes in one text string. If any of the volumes have less then %5 free space I'd like to trigger a critical warning.

This is the code so far:

```
# Import Cluster Shared Volumes module to Powershell
Import-Module FailoverClusters

# Flush object
$objs = @()

# Gather info from the ClusterSharedVolume
$csvs = Get-ClusterSharedVolume
foreach ( $csv in $csvs )
{
    $csvinfos = $csv | select -Property Name -ExpandProperty SharedVolumeInfo
        $new_obj = $objs | select  Name,Path,
        @{ Name = ($csv.Name) },
        @{ Path = ($csvinfo.FriendlyVolumeName) },
        @{ Label = "Size(GB)" ; Expression = { "{0:N1}" -f ($csvinfo.Partition.Size / 1GB) } },   
        @{ Label = "FreeSpace(GB)" ; Expression = { "{0:N1}" -f ($csvinfo.Partition.FreeSpace / 1GB) } },    
        @{ Label = "UsedSpace(GB)" ; Expression = { "{0:N1}" -f ($csvinfo.Partition.UsedSpace / 1GB) } },    
        @{ Label = "PercentFree" ; Expression = { "{0:N2}" -f ($csvinfo.Partition.PercentFree) } }

$objs += $new_obj
}

$objs
```

I know that I have some basic errors here... My script is simply returning the proper amount of objects, but all are the same. 
Please advice:)

Answer (score 0):

you're not defining "$csvinfo" anywhere, only "$csvinfos".